# Count and match related documents in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: `Tests` and `Reports`. They are related and `Reports` have field test with `Test.id`. Each `Test` document have `testers_count` field.

Also I have written query should returns only `Tests` with `testers_count` greater or equal than `count` of related `Reports` docs.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: 'reports',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'test',
          as: 'reportsList'
        }
    },
    {
       $match: {
        "settings.testers_count": {$gte: {$size: "$reportsList"}}
       }
    }
])
```

The problem is the code does not work nor returns any error.

Comment: Is the collection named `Reports` or `reports`?

Comment: @Blakes You are right, the $match is "incorrect". As I understand the value should be number or string. But it's an difficult to understand without errors (

Comment: That's why there is an "answer" to the question. `$match` is not the correct usage in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that you actually mean:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "reports",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "test",
    "as": "reportsList"
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { 
        "$gte": [ 
            "$settings.testers_count",
            { "$size": "$reportsLIst" }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Presuming that `$settings.testers_count` actually resolves to a "singular" property, and is not the member of an "array".

Which uses [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) instead and the "logical" form of [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) for the evaluation.

Also the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator can only be used in such an evaluation expression as [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) allows. The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator is really just the same in concept and operator syntax to `.find()`, in that it performs a "query", and can really only use the "query operators" and **no** calculated logical expressions.

This is what [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) is actually for. It's a "logical expression" form of [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)